# I want to have a column in MySQL database that automatically calculates difference in DATETIME

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In MySQL database, I have the following table that stores work clock in and clock out times. I would like the hours column to auto calculate the DATETIME difference in the database.

```
ID  Clock In  Clock Out  Hours
```

```
1   10:00     17:00      7
2   09:00     16:00      7
3   09:00     15:30      6.5
```

The SQL statement im using to preview the results is:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, `clock_in`, `clock_out`) as `difference` FROM records
```

I just want to know how i can apply this to the hours column in the db to auto populate when records are created.

Comment: You can use an trigger on that table! https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for a *view* instead of duplicating information in another column.

Comment: [MySQL 5.7 supports computed columns ("Generated Columns")](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: Could i get an example of how i would correlate the above SQL statement to a trigger event or computed column? Thanks!

Comment: You've been given a link from @JustOnUnderMillions to consult; there are examples in there. And from Mark.

Comment: @JackieJoyce Here are a few good tutorials on TRIGGERS that you can have a look at http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx --- http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-triggers.php --- https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/introduction-to-mysql-triggers--net-12226 --- You need to make sure that there are privileges set in order to use a TRIGGER.

Comment: (1) `TIMESTAMPDIFF` only returns integers. (2) If your columns are `TIME` data, things are going to get weird on the overnight shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you want is to use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_records AS
    SELECT v.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, `clock_in`, `clock_out`) as `difference`
    FROM records;
```

This conveniently calculates the value when it is *used*.  That ensures that the most recent data is used for the calculation.

If you want to get fancy, you can write a trigger.  However, you need to deal with both updates and inserts.